# How to make DataGrip show more output tab

Tags: datagrip

When I run SQL statements one by one, DataGrip will only show the last two output tabs in its console window, just like this:

[image: datagrip]

However I can run SQL statements one time，and Datagrip can show more than two tabs.

Can anyone tell me how to set DataGrip to keep more output tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Press *Restore Layout* on the left panel
[image]